# Do you have to have the Dawnguard DLC to become a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Do I have to have the Dawnguard DLC to become a werewolf in Skyrim? I'm buying the game just for me to become one so please answer my question.

Answer (score 25):

No, to become a werewolf you must do some quests in the Companions quest line, which is available without Dawnguard. In Dawnguard, you get the ability to turn into a Vampire Lord.

Long story short, no, you do not need the Dawnguard DLC to become a werewolf.

Comment: A source for this can be found in the UESP page about [Lycanthropy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lycanthropy). The only thing Dawnguard adds to this is a skill perks tree.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need Dawnguard DLC to be werewolf. But having Dawnguard, you will have another tree perk for werewolf that will give your werewolf more edge than being an ordinary werewolf without the Dawnguard DLC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can Become a werewolf within the base game by doing two main quest missions and then two Radiant quests for the companions, I am unsure whether or not random werewolf attacks give you the disease of lycanthropy, but , I do know for definite that with the dawngaurd DLC, You can become a vampire way easier due to the more concurrent vampire attacks, That will happen on a regular, this does not make you a vampire lord only Lord Harkon and Sarana Can bestow that gift. :)

Answer (score -3):

You don't need it, but if you have Dawnguard, werewolves will encounter randomly, meaning you don't have to do quests, just gotta stay alive from them.

Comment: Dawnguard is what I meant.

Comment: You're confusing werewolves with vampires